# Updated Entity Field is not persisting

Tags: symfony

I have updated my entity by adding a new field.

Added entity is,

```
    /**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="eid", type="integer",nullable=true)
 */
private $eventId;
```

Also I have added a getter/setter for the same.

Following code is for saving the entity back into the database.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $eventNotice = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ZAAdminBundle:EventNotice')->findOneById(373);
    $eventNotice->setEventId(1234);
    $em->persist($eventNotice);
    $em->flush();
```

This code is running successfully but not persisting value for EventId for rest entity fields these are persisting properly.

Can anyone please suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: Have you actually created the field at your database?

Comment: Can you paste your entity code?

Comment: Yes! I have created the field at my database

Comment: What database type are you using? Maybe 'eid' has some special meaning.

Comment: you mean that I must try by changing field name?

Comment: Before persisting, do you mind doing dump($eventNotice); to check if eventId was successfuly set?

Comment: I have checked this by getEventId getter method and it is returning a value properly.

Comment: I have observed that, Rest data is saving correctly as it's sql query is created correctly. new entity field is not in the query actually so it is saving without error and not saving updated field too.

Comment: As you say that your getter returns the expected value, I suppose that you have a typo problem both in your setter and your getter. Probably you do something like `$this->eventid` instead of `$this->eventId`. If so, it will not be saved in your DB as it is not modifying the good attribute.